# pymodbus TcpClient timeout

Tags: python, connection-timeout, modbus

I have problem with pymodbus TcpClient timeout:

```
import logging
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = ModbusTcpClient('x.y.z.w', port=yyy)
client.connect()

result = client.read_holding_registers(10, 10)
print(result.registers)
client.close()
```

Error:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Transaction failed. (timed out)
ERROR:pymodbus.client.sync:Connection to (x.y.z.w, yyy) failed: [Errno 10061] ╧юфъы■ўхэшх эх єёЄрэютыхэю,
```

Modpool with tiomeot=1  I have error:

```
modpoll.exe -c 5 -r 10 -o 1 -p yyy -m tcp x.y.z.w
-- Polling slave... (Ctrl-C to stop)
Reply time-out!
```

But with timeout=10 all goods:

```
modpoll.exe -c 5 -r 10 -o 10 -p yyy -m tcp x.y.z.w
-- Polling slave... (Ctrl-C to stop)
[10]: 2
[11]: 10
[12]: 10
[13]: 10
```

- How change default timeout in pymodbus TcpClient?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
client = ModbusTcpClient('x.y.z.w', port=yyy, timeout=10)
```

it works for rtu in pymodbus.

Comment: Question was specifically about Modbus/TCP, not Modbus/RTU.

Comment: I can confirm it is working with ```ModbusTcpClient``` tried as the code example suggested

Answer (score 4):

```
from pymodbus.constants import Defaults

Defaults.Timeout = 10
client = ModbusTcpClient('x.y.z.w', port=yyy)
client.connect()
```

`ModbusTcpClient` class doesn't have any argument in it's constructor or specific method to pass the `timeout` to the class. Instead, one can change the `timeout` of the class by globally changing the `timeout` variable using the `Defaults` which consequently affects the `ModbusTcpClient` connection `timeout` variable.

Comment: Please explain your answers!

Comment: Pymodbus ModbusTcpClient now supports setting a timeout value directly during instantiation, as of v 1.3.0.

Comment: Specifically 1.3.0.rc2.  Like so: `ModbusTcpClient( ..., timeout=5 )`  Reference: https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#version-1-3-0-rc2